# postgres not releasing memory after big query

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

When I run a query in postgres it will load in memory all the data it needs for query execution but when the query finishes executing the memory consumed by postgres is not released.

I run postgres with the Timescaledb extension installed, which already stores 93 million records, the request to get all these 93 million records takes 13GB of RAM and 21mins. After the request, RAM is reduced to 9GB and holds it.

How can I release all this memory?

Here's my postgresql.conf memory section.

```
shared_buffers = 8GB  
huge_pages = try  
huge_page_size = 0      
temp_buffers = 8MB                
max_prepared_transactions = 0  
work_mem = 5118kB  
hash_mem_multiplier = 1.0   
maintenance_work_mem = 2047MB  
autovacuum_work_mem = -1   
logical_decoding_work_mem = 64MB  
max_stack_depth = 2MB       
shared_memory_type = mmap  
effective_cache_size = 4GB
```

[image]

**UPD 15.12.2022**

@jjanes Yes, you were right. As a colleague and I found out, memory usage is not exactly what we thought about from the very beginning.

As we also understood from the **free -m -h**, when a request uses more memory than configured, the remaining data begins to be loaded into **cache/buffer**.

[image]

When we clean **cache/buffer** after big query, memory usage for this service drops to 8,53GB. This occupied memory +- coincides with the value of **shared_buffers = 8GB**, it practically does not decrease. For large requests, postgres still continues to use to request large chunks of memory from **cache/buffer**.

It turns out that we need to somehow clean the cache of postgres itself, since it does not release it itself?

[image]

Comment: You need to disconnect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean? Should I disconnect from postgres or what? And how it helps me?

Comment: We don't know what you are actually measuring.  It says "Memory Usage", but there are a lot of ways that that can be measured.

Comment: Right. It could be the kernel page cache that you are seeing. That's the problem with graphical monitoring: they often don't show you *what exactly* you are seeing here.